# Update from zfs-0.6.2-1.el6.x86_64 to zfs-0.6.3-1.el6.x86_64 has made by zpool unreadable

Tags: linux, centos6, zfs, zfsonlinux

After running `# yum update zfs` and restarting my `CentOS 6` `ZFS on Linux` system can no longer see or interact with it's zpools.

```
# zpool status
no pools available
# zpool import
zpool: ../../lib/libzfs/libzfs_import.c:356: Assertion `nvlist_lookup_uint64(zhp->zpool_config, ZPOOL_CONFIG_POOL_GUID, &theguid) == 0' failed.
Aborted
# dmesg | grep -i spl 
SPL: Loaded module v0.6.2-1 
SPL: using hostid 0x43a4c8a0
```

This is a canary system, so I'm not worried about its contents, but I have other machines that I would eventually like to upgrade safely. What did I do wrong, and more importantly how can I do it right for the important systems?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That looks like...a bug. In fact, [it is a bug](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2400). The ZFS userland is updated, but the kernel modules aren't being updated by DKMS. This assertion is caused by the version mismatch.

You can work around it by a process given in a [comment](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2400#issuecomment-46118193) to the bug, by removing the old kernel modules and then reinstalling everything.

```
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra -name "splat.ko" -or -name "zcommon.ko" -or -name "zpios.ko" -or -name "spl.ko" -or -name "zavl.ko" -or -name "zfs.ko" -or -name "znvpair.ko" -or -name "zunicode.ko" | xargs rm -f
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/weak-updates -name "splat.ko" -or -name "zcommon.ko" -or -name "zpios.ko" -or -name "spl.ko" -or -name "zavl.ko" -or -name "zfs.ko" -or -name "znvpair.ko" -or -name "zunicode.ko" | xargs rm -f
$ yum reinstall zfs-release
$ yum reinstall $(rpm -qa | egrep "zfs|spl")
```

Answer (score 5):

This came up in discussion on the [ZFS mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/zfsonlinux.org/forum/#!topic/zfs-discuss/eeg3FdJ8xss).

> The kernel ABI changed between 0.6.2 and 0.6.3 in such a way that 
>   0.6.3 user-land tools can't interact with 0.6.2 kernel modules, which  is the configuration after upgrading to 0.6.3.  According to numerous 
>   messages on this list, the right approach is simply to reboot.

This is covered in the ZFS bug report: https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2400#issuecomment-46118193

I only use ZFS for data partitions, so I uninstalled the packages, got rid of the weak-modules references and reinstalled ZFS.

```
# rpm -e `rpm -qa | egrep '(spl|zfs)'`
# cd /lib/modules/2.6.32-431.17.1.el6.x86_64/weak-updates/
# rm -fr spl* z*
# yum localinstall --nogpgcheck http://archive.zfsonlinux.org/epel/zfs-release$(rpm -E %dist).noarch.rpm
# yum install zfs
```

**Edit**: I still had to reboot.

***Edit:***

Following both workarounds presented resulted in some problems with the ZFS installation. There are some issues with module loading due to a critical missing parameter (`zfs: Unknown parameter`zfs_vdev_max_pending'`). I'd deem this release unsafe for general release or blind updates on existing systems.

Answer (score 4):

If you ever end up on this page and your running `Debian`, you only have to do the following to fix the issue:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

The issue occurred because a simple `update` doesn't not replace old library files with the newer ones. This is why a `dist-upgrade` is needed. From the [apt-get manpage](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=apt-get):

> **dist-upgrade** in addition to performing the function of upgrade, also intelligently handles 
>   changing dependencies with new versions of packages; apt-get has a "smart" conflict 
>   resolution system, and it will attempt to upgrade the most important packages at the 
>   expense of less important ones if necessary. The dist-upgrade command may therefore 
>   remove some packages.

Source: http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/75-debian/312-debian-wheezy-zfsonlinux-zpool-lost

Comment: distr-upgrade is the solution: `REMOVED: libzfs1 libzpool1` `installed: libzfs2 libzpool2`