# ZFS on linux upgrade from 0.6.2 to 0.6.3 made my zpool unreadable help translate CentOS to Ubuntu commands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, zfsonlinux

After upgrading my `ubuntu 13.10` server using `sudo apt-get upgrade` and rebooting, my zpool wouldn't show.

```
messier@ANDERSON:~$ sudo zpool status
no pools available
messier@ANDERSON:~$ sudo zpool import
zpool: ../../lib/libzfs/libzfs_import.c:356: Assertion `nvlist_lookup_uint64(zhp->zpool_config, ZPOOL_CONFIG_POOL_GUID, &theguid) == 0' failed.
messier@ANDERSON:~$
```

I looked on the zfs on linux github and I found [a fix for CentOS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2400) which is to remove the old kernel modules and then reinstall the software to get the new kernel modules.

```
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra -name "splat.ko" -or -name "zcommon.ko" -or -name "zpios.ko" -or -name "spl.ko" -or -name "zavl.ko" -or -name "zfs.ko" -or -name "znvpair.ko" -or -name "zunicode.ko" | xargs rm -f
$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/weak-updates -name "splat.ko" -or -name "zcommon.ko" -or -name "zpios.ko" -or -name "spl.ko" -or -name "zavl.ko" -or -name "zfs.ko" -or -name "znvpair.ko" -or -name "zunicode.ko" | xargs rm -f
$ yum reinstall zfs-release
$ yum reinstall $(rpm -qa | egrep "zfs|spl")
```

People are saying this is fixing it. I just don't know how to make this fix run on my ubuntu server.
Thank you for the help!

Last edit : **If you come onto this page for the zfs update bug. The easiest solution is like Scott Simon said.**

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

Comment: Interesting. I'll ask on the ZFS list.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meaant on the Zfs on linux github, I also added a link to the issue stating the fix. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/q/606215/195746

Comment: It may be duplicate on the error, but since the OS is different, I thought the solution would be different.

Comment: Had this problem after `do-release-upgrade`. The solution worked for me but only after I did : `apt-add-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ sudo find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates -name "splat.ko" -or -name "zcommon.ko" -or -name "zpios.ko" -or -name "spl.ko" -or -name "zavl.ko" -or -name "zfs.ko" -or -name "znvpair.ko" -or -name "zunicode.ko" | xargs rm -f
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-zfs
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg-query --show --showformat='${binary:Package}\n' | egrep 'spl|zfs')
```

---

Ubuntu keeps all its dkms in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates`, rather than in `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/extra` and `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/weak-updates` as CentOS does.

`yum resinstall` is equivalent to `apt-get install --reinstall`.
Ubuntu's zfs metapackage is `ubuntu-zfs` instead of `zfs-release` as it is in CentOS.
`rpm -qa` is equivalent to `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${binary:Package}\n'`

I'm also uncertain if the find command actually needs to be run, as `apt-get` may take care of that already, but running it won't break the process.

Someone with more knowledge of or experience with `dpkg` may be able to write a marginally more efficient command, but I suspect this is good enough for most purposes.

Comment: Thank you for this! I've worked out my solution from your post! If you are curious I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The [official bug page](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/issues/2400) has this fix for Ubuntu and Debian users:

```
# apt-get update
# apt-get dist-upgrade
# reboot
```

Comment: Had this problem after `do-release-upgrade`. This worked for me only after I did : `apt-add-repository ppa:zfs-native/stable`

Comment: distr-upgrade is the solution: `REMOVED: libzfs1 libzpool1` `installed: libzfs2 libzpool2`

Answer (score 2):

I have debian-zfs installed on proxmox 3.2 (using this kernel pve-headers-2.6.32-26-pve).
This is how I fixed it after the upgrade.

```
aptitude purge dkms debian-zfs spl-dkms zfs-dkms
```

I chose "Yes" to all the prompts, to remove it all.
After that was done, I did some checking if there are any dkms leftovers. The below command should show an empty directory.

```
ls /lib/modules/2.6.32-26-pve/updates/dkms/
```

If you see anything in there (the above directory), you need to delete it all **(unless you have other custom kernel modules)**.

Then it was as simple as:

```
apt-get install debian-zfs
```

Then import my pool (my pool is called tank):

```
zpool import tank
```

zfs got upset because it was not properly exported before all the drama happened.

```
cannot import 'tank': pool may be in use on another system
```

That's not a problem, I tried again with this:

```
zpool import -f tank
```

The above worked, and I was able to see my pool with this command:

```
zpool status
    root@proxmox-01:~# zpool status
  pool: tank
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 0h8m with 0 errors on Tue Jul  8 20:39:13 2014
config:

        NAME                                           STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
        tank                                           ONLINE       0     0     0
          raidz2-0                                     ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1001FALS-_WD-WMATV4198253  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1002FAEX-_WD-WCAW30398837  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1002FAEX-_WD-WCAW30404054  ONLINE       0     0     0
            scsi-SATA_WDC_WD1002FAEX-_WD-WCAW30406039  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

I was happy with this. But proxmox was a little bit more difficult.
I had to mess about with the mount point for proxmox, because it automatically creates the directory structure of "storage" that you add to proxmox.

First I check if `/tank` was not lovely zfs pool, using `du -hs /tank`. My pool has a lot of stuff in it, a lot more than 12KB.

I export (disconnect) my zfs pool `zpool export tank`

I removed the EMPTY `/tank` directory with `rm -R /tank` **(please double check!!)**

Then I import my pool (connect) `zpool import tank` and your zfs storage should be working, and accessible to proxmox.

This is how I got my zfs to work on proxmox in the first place:

http://www.anotherlan.com/proxmox-zfs-on-linux-local-storage

Comment: upgrading my zfs on linux from 0.6.3 to 0.6.4 was painless, do not forget to upgrade your zpool:
`zpool upgrade tank`

Answer (score 0):

User 84104's solution "worked". I did the first line of it. Then the rest didn't quite work. So I tried `sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-zfs dkms` and then `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-zfs dkms` and the same error occured. Dkms did not recognized that the zfs/0.6.3 and spl/0.6.3 was different from the one that comes with the 3.11.0-23-generic kernel. So I went and used `sudo dkms remove zfs/0.6.3 --all` and `sudo dkms remove zfs/0.6.3 --all` and then I forced the install of both modules using `sudo dkms install zfs/0.6.3 --force` and `sudo dkms install spl/0.6.3 --force`

Basically the solution is to use dkms to remove the modules and then force back the install of 0.6.3.